# What is the minimum set of required protocols for VoIP calls?

Tags: sip, voip, rtp, rfc

I've been reading about Voice Over IP and it's still not clear to me which protocols (i.e. RFCs) you have to implement to support audio calls between two IP-endpoints where the two endpoints might not reside on the same network.

So far I understand that:

- RTP (RFC 3550) is used for audio payload transport
- SIP (RFC 3261) is used for signaling
- SDP (RFC 4566) is used for media negotiation (i.e. which codec to use)
- RTCP (RFC 3550) is used for transmission stats

So if I'm not mistaken it should be possible to establish a SIP audio call between two devices with the 3 above mentioned protocols (?)

But what I'm not totally sure about is :

- Which RFCs do you need to implement to ensure that a SIP audio call can be established between two devices which reside on different (firewalled) networks ?

Comment: This proves more fitting for serverfault and/or somewhat superuser

Comment: I see lots of SIP questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPort (RFC 3851) is very simple and helps a lot for the SIP messages and firewalls. Otherwise firewall/NAT traversal is a huge can of worms. There are protocols such as TURN and ICE, and simple techniques such as checking and modifying IP addresses that won't be in any RFC. Your RFC list is good by the way though RTCP is still largely optional.

Comment: So an implementation of 3 protocols is enough (disregarding NAT traversal issues) ? How do most SIP phones get around these NAT traversal issues?

Comment: Depends on type of NAT, port forwarding etc its a big subject with no one solution. For example, look at options in XLite. Probably ok to begin with using rport, and knowing your external addresses.

Comment: And yes, for minimal implementation you just need SIP, SDP and RTP.